# MacOS and Mono Cannot start .NET Core language services because `dotnet` was not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

I installed mono on my macos using brew. I also installed VSCode and installed Ionide extension.

I got this error

```
Cannot start .NET Core language services because `dotnet` was not found. 
Consider: * setting the `FSharp.dotnetLocation` settings key to a `dotnet` 
binary, * including `dotnet` in your PATH, * installing .NET Core into one of 
the default locations, or * using the `net` `FSharp.fsacRuntime` to use mono
```

instead

I have installed Mono but I don't know where should the location of `FSharp.fsacRuntime` point too.

If you have used F# and mono on a mac can you please let me know how can this error be overcome?

Edit: I am very very confused by 1 liner comments as answers. Sorry but these are not newbie friendly. I had done googling and installed mono based on advice given here https://fsharp.org/use/mac/. Now everyone is contradicting it.

Can someone point me to a blog which says how to setup a kick ass F# environment on Mac/Linux. Also everything should be installed via package managers like apt or brew.

So I removed mono from my machine and Installed .NET core using instructions here http://www.joshka.net/2016/08/installing-dotnet-osx

And now my Fsharp compiler and FSharp REPL are gone.

Comment: You installed Mono, but the error message is asking for .NET Core. Those are different things.

Comment: Install dotnet SDK (and quickly forget about Mono) from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core (dotnet core 3 preview 9 works reasonably well).

Comment: OK so now I'm very confused. Is there a blog which shows how to configure a fully functional working environment on a Mac for F#? I found mono to be very convenient because its supported by brew.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/install-fsharp?tabs=windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode Since Mono is a port of .NET on Unix, and .NET and .dotnecore are heading for unification in v5, you should really install dotnet core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x A short-cut could be to just install Visual Studio for MAC but use Rider or VSCode instead.

Comment: A few pointers as I've also had challenges with the same recently... (1) If an installation of whatever you're trying to install doesn't work, don't give up after trying using `brew` - try using manual install method. (2) Learn how to add things to your path, plenty of guides about this around. (3) From a command prompt you can type `where mono`. (4) Use commands such as `mono --version` to help protect your sanity. (5) Unless you are trying to run full asp.net framework projects or fsharp interactive, you may be fine with just dotnet core.

Comment: I installed .NET for mac via download link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/ and all was fine. On terminal I can call `dotnet --help` with no errors. But I still have the same error message via Ionide plugin. `Cannot start .NET Core language services because dotnet was not found.` Any help?